# Consuming an authenticated web service using SAAJ?

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, ssl, saaj

I am trying to consume an authenticated webservice using SAAJ. This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import javax.xml.soap.*;
import biz.source_code.base64Coder.*;


public class Client {
    private static String endpoint = "https://example.com/xxx.php",
    username = "xxx", password = "xxx";

    private static SOAPMessage getRequest() throws Exception{
        MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();

        //set authorization as a HTTP header
        String authorization = Base64Coder.encodeString(username + ":" + password);
        MimeHeaders hd = message.getMimeHeaders();
        hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);

        //Call getReportList operation


        return message;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SOAPConnectionFactory connFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection connection = connFactory.createConnection();

        // create request message and give it content
        SOAPMessage request = Client.getRequest();

        // call the API endpoint with the request
        SOAPMessage response = connection.call(request, endpoint);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.writeTo(out);
        String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(strMsg);
    }

}
```

When I run this, it prints strMsg (response from the web service) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>WSDL</faultcode><faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '/www/example.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "/www/example.wsdl"
</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am guessing I have authenticated myself but there was a problem with the web service not mine. But, I am not entirely sure. This error message doesn't seem that common.

Does this mean the authentication I provided was incorrect or insufficient? Or do I have to provide the SSL certificate because the web service uses SSL? If yes, Is there a tutorial on how to use SSL certificates with SAAJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using "https://example.com/xxx.php" as the endpoint not "https://example.com/xxx.php?wsdl". That's why it couldn't load any wsdl file.